# Dúvida em consulta SQL com Group by e Order by

Tags: sql, firebird

Boa tarde Galera!!!

Tenho uma consulta sql que é simples, mas que estou tendo uma dificuldade para realizar um order by em dois campos ao mesmo tempo. Tal consulta é pra eu montar um relatório, mas antes de montar preciso validar essa consulta. A consulta que está sendo realizada é essa:

```
select 
   cped.razsocial,
   cped.nrpedido,
   iped.codbarra,
   iped.codprod,
   iped.qtde,
   iped.descricao,
   funcionario.fantasia,
   cped.dtpedido,
   produto.observacao,
   cped.liberado,
   cped.statusweb
from cped

inner join iped on (cped.nrpedido = iped.nrpedido)
inner join produto on (iped.codprod = produto.codprod)
inner join funcionario on (cped.indicacao = funcionario.funcionario)
inner join almox on (cped.almoxarifado = almox.codigo )

where (
  (cped.tipo = 'Z') )


group by 
  cped.razsocial,
  cped.nrpedido,
  iped.codbarra,
  iped.codprod,
  iped.qtde,
  iped.descricao,
  funcionario.fantasia,
  cped.dtpedido,
  produto.observacao,
  cped.liberado,
  cped.statusweb

order by iped.descricao,cped.nrpedido
```

Ao executar o comando dá certo, no entanto ele só ordena pelo iped.descricao. Preciso que ele ordene pela descrição mas que o campo cped.nrpedido esteja junto, ou seja, se o cliente tem 3 itens dentro do pedido com descrições de itens diferentes, que ele não jogue o nrpedido no fim da lista, mas deixe agrupado.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Como não há nenhuma função de agregação, a cláusula GROUP BY é inútil, nesse caso. Exceto se foi utilizada para eliminar linhas repetidas...

Answer (score -1):

### TL;DR;

Se eu inferi corretamente o seu modelo, para obter o resultado desejado seu `order by` deve ser assim:

```
order by cped.razsocial, cped.nrpedido, iped.descricao
```

### Explicando

Você não ordena por *dois campos ao mesmo tempo*. Você ordena por um campo e em seguida por outro.

Acho que você confundiu um pouco o conceito do ordenamento. Veja bem, supondo o seguinte conjunto de dados:

```
joão  | banana  | 1
joão  | maçã    | 1
maria | banana  | 2
maria | banana  | 3
maria | maça    | 3
maria | banana  | 4
joão  | maçã    | 5
joão  | acerola | 5
maria | acerola | 6
```

De acordo com **sua consulta**, o resultado do ordenamento para esse conjunto de dados seria assim:

```
joão  | acerola | 5
maria | acerola | 6
joão  | banana  | 1
maria | banana  | 2
maria | banana  | 3
maria | banana  | 4
joão  | maçã    | 1
maria | maça    | 3
joão  | maçã    | 5
```

Ou seja: está ordenado pela **descrição dos itens** e ***em seguida*** pelo **número do pedido**. Primeiro vão aparecer todas acerolas com os seus pedido e depois vão aparecer as bananas para só então listar as maçãs. Independentemente de em que pedido esses itens tenham sido feitos.

Pelo seu texto, sua expectativa seria esse resultado:

```
joão  | banana  | 1
joão  | maçã    | 1
joão  | maçã    | 5
joão  | acerola | 5
maria | banana  | 2
maria | banana  | 3
maria | maça    | 3
maria | banana  | 4
maria | acerola | 6
```

Em outras palavras: Ordenado pelo **cliente**, ***em seguida*** pelo **pedido** e ***em seguida*** pela **descrição do item**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Bom dia Diego, agradeço pela resposta! 
O primeiro campo que preciso iniciar ordenando seria a descrição do produto. Entendi sua explicação, mas como tenho a solicitação de iniciar ordenando por este campo, preciso ordenar a relação de produtos sem perder a relação do pedido, ou seja, ordenando por descrição e mantendo os produtos juntos ao mesmo pedido.

Comment: @JhonnyCosta isso seria uma contradição. As duas coisas são mutuamente exclusivas. Ou você entendeu a explicação (e abre mão do que você pensou) ou você continua insistindo na outra linha de pensamento (e você não entendeu).

Comment: No último exemplo que eu dei, pelo que você está falando você estaria querendo que aparecesse `acerola` do pedido `5` do `joão`, depois a `maçã` do pedido `5` do `joão` e em seguida a `acerola` do pedido `6` da `maria`... Se esse for o caso, o seu resultset não está ordenado pela descrição do item, pois se estivessem todas as `acerolas` deveriam aparecer antes das `maçãs` (o que obrigaria a quebrar os pedidos)

Comment: Isso mesmo que explica o fato de você ter incluído um `group by` para todas as colunas e não estar usando nenhuma função de agragação ou ainda fazer um `join` solto com o `almox` sem usá-la para qualquer fim. Ou isso é um outro requisito não explicitado na pergunta (nesse caso teria entrado no [mcve] por engano) ou realmente os seus requisitos / consulta não fazem mesmo sentido